# mapStateToProps has no effect on props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my react-redux app, `mapStateToProps` apparently has no effect on props. I am doing this:

```
this.props.dispatch(simClear());
console.log(this.props);
```

This is the action creater:

```
export function simClear() {
  return {type: 'SIM_CLEAR'};
}
```

...and the reducer:

```
registerReducer('sim', function(state=initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SIM_CLEAR': return {...state, progs: []};
    [...]
    default: return state;
  }
});

[...]

const registerReducer = function(id, reducer) {
    reducers[id] = reducer;
}

const getCombinedReducers = function() {
    return combineReducers(reducers);
}
```

And mapStateToProps looks like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {  
  return {
    progs: state.sim.progs,
    [...]
  };
}
```

Through test output I verified that the action gets created and dispatched, the reducer gets called and returns an updated state, then `mapStateToProps` gets called with the updated state and returns the expected object (in which `progs` is an empty array). All this looks good.

But then, the console outputs the **old** props (with the old value of `progs`). Why???

There is no asynchronousness in my own code and a test output in `mapStateToProps` prints before the `console.log(this.props)`.

Comment: `console.log(this.props);` immediately after `this.props.dispatch(simClear());` may print old `props` because component can update asynchronously.

Comment: try console logging inside `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: Isn't redux supposed to be synchronous?

Comment: @Prakashsharma What do you mean? I thought dispatching an action was sync

Comment: Check the duplicate question